# XML Deserialization into multiple objects using comma separated fields

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, deserialization, delimiter

I would like to be able to deserialize a single XML file into a list/array of objects of the same type. Certain fields within the XML file are to be comma separated (or separated by some other character) to uniquely specify that value within each object. For example, the following XML

```
<packet_type xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <version>1</version>
  <one_hertz>
    <field_one>true</field_one>
    <field_two>enum_one,enum_two,enum_three</field_two>
    <field_three>this is a string,this is a different string,...</field_three>
  </one_hertz>
</packet_type>
```

should be deserialized such that three objects are created and filled out accordingly:

- object[0].version = 1
- object[0].one_hertz.field_one = true
- object[0].one_hertz.field_two = enum_one
- object[0].one_hertz.field_three = "this is a string"
- object[1].version = 1
- object[1].one_hertz.field_one = true
- object[1].one_hertz.field_two = enum_two
- object[1].one_hertz.field_three = "this is a different string"
- object[2].version = 1
- object[2].one_hertz.field_one = true
- object[2].one_hertz.field_two = enum_three
- object[2].one_hertz.field_three = "..."

My knowledge of XML serialization/deserialization is limited, so I'm wondering if this is at all feasible with existing libraries. The number of objects to deserialize will be upwards of 10 and the objects I'll be dealing with are much more complicated, so I'd like to be able to define unique values concisely without having to define an entire XML structure for each object. Am I better off writing a parser from the ground up, or is there an easier solution?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a single deserialization but you can deserialize it first to a simple class and then do a post processing to split it to multiple objects.

Comment: Do you really think that's a well designed XML? I don't think so, and would rather advice changing the XML design then trying to deserialize it as it is now.

Comment: That's a transposed CSV wrapped into XML. What about `input.UnWrap().UnTranspose().ParseCsv()`? :-D

Comment: Please do not invent custom formats which require multiple layers of encoding. If you don't like XML - use JSON, but please use one that already thought about encoding characters (and CSV is not good one, because there is really no common standard on encoding commas/quotes).

Comment: On other hand if goal is to make life of future developers more painful - indeed Base64 individual values (some, definitely not all and not ones that may have `\01` characters in future), than put resulting CSV in JSON and than set resulting value as attributes in XML. :)